# How to read raw from an arbitrary file without knowing the size?

Tags: r

I see the following error. Is this error related to the size of the memory on my machine? If I want to make it be able to read an arbitrary file that is allowed by R, but the size is unknown, how to make `readBin()` work in this way?

```
$ Rscript main.R
R> con=file('testbin', 'wb')
R> object=list(1:10)
R> print(serialize(object, NULL))
  [1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 04 00 03 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 ee 00 00 00 02 00 00
 [42] 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 0e 63 6f 6d 70 61 63 74 5f 69 6e 74 73 65 71 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 09 00 00 00 04 62
 [83] 61 73 65 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 fe 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 03 40 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f f0
[124] 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fe
R> writeBin(serialize(object, NULL), con)
R> close(con)
R> con=file('testbin', 'rb')
R> unserialize(readBin(con, what=raw(), n=2L**36-1))
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Execution halted
```

Comment: use `file.info()$size` to find the size of the file so you know how many bytes you will need to read.

Comment: no. I don't need to find the size of the file as the input can be from a pipe.

Comment: and you're on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Please open it.

Comment: Yes. 64bit Mac OS. But the solution should be cross platform.

Comment: But your example doesn't use pipes at all. If it was streaming in a pipe, you'd need to read the data in chunks in a loop.

Comment: I've already said without knowing its size. Any solution needs to know its size is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that an input stream would never end. You need an upper limit on the data you read in one chunk. There's no way to handle any input of a (possibly) infinite size. Start with a number much smaller than `2L**36-1` and loop over the input if needed. For example you can do

```
bindata <- raw(0)
con=file('testbin', 'rb')
while (TRUE) {
  chunk <- readBin(con, what=raw(), n=1024)
  if (length(chunk)==0) {
    break
  } else {
    bindata <- c(bindata, chunk)
  }
}
close(con)
```

There's no check here on size either, but you could add a check to the `while` loop and warn of errors before you exhaust your memory.

Comment: This is not efficient (t ~ n^2) due to the use of c. An efficient solution is needed.

Comment: I'd think there is a deficiency of readBin. It seems that n could be a negative number to indicate that the read is until EOF.

Comment: The input length is arbitrary but finite.

Comment: Change your `n` to something that it better for your data. At some level you need to do dynamic memory allocation. If you don't know how big something is going to, you need to keep requesting larger chunks at recombining in memory. Is this really a bottle neck for you? If this is something you need to optimize you can always write custom C++ code for your purpose. This is just not a common use case for R.